# Cloud storage on development server is deleting the uploaded file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've created a jpg file using PIL and I want to store that image on the cloud service. In production that cloud service already has a bucket with images in it from the previous implementation that used my computer to create the image and upload it, but that costs a lot of electricity so I re-wrote the application in python so I was hoping to put the entire thing on the google app engine. The main application that serves the images runs PHP, this new thing I'm developing is a module to that application that runs python.

The PHP code was able to produce an upload url using the correct gs_bucket_name like this:

```
$storage = new CloudStorageTools();
$url = $storage->createUploadUrl("/process_file",['gs_bucket_name' => 'my_bucket']);
echo("URL: $url\n");
```

My computer could upload to that url and files would appear in the dev server and eventually on the live version it worked well too and a lot of images got uploaded. I was using curl to do that like this:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/_ah/upload/ahFkZXZ-d2ltdm8tbWFycy0zZHIiCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGICAgICA-IULDA --form file=somefilename.jpg
```

I must add that this is also no longer working right now on the dev server (from the PHP side)

On the python side I am doing something similar, but all in one go now:
Do note that I am still trying to call the callback function on my default PHP module once the image is uploaded.

```
callback = "http://%s/process_file" % modules.get_hostname(module="default")
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url(callback,gs_bucket_name="my_bucket")
outputstream = cStringIO.StringIO()
outputdata.save(outputstream, format="JPEG", optimized=True, quality=90)
files = []
files.append(MultipartParam("file", filename = filename, filetype = 'image/jpeg', value = outputstream.getvalue()))
outputstream.close()
data, headers = multipart_encode(files)
headers.pop('Content-Length',None)
result = urlfetch.fetch(
  url = upload_url,
  payload="".join(data),
  method=urlfetch.POST,
  headers=headers,
  follow_redirects = False)
```

However, when I run this, it appears as if the uploaded file is instantly deleted:

The upload url's that I'm getting have a different port number because they are now served by the processing module (python) and no longer the default module (php) e.g. `http://localhost:51022/_ah/upload/ahFkZXZ-d2ltdm8tbWFycy0zZHIiCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGICAgICA-MULDA`
and on the console log I see:

```
INFO     2016-01-24 10:48:30,891 module.py:787] proc_mod: "DELETE /_ah/gcs/my_bucket/fake-pywzB198-jubU_Kcl-REhA%3D%3D HTTP/1.1" 204 -
INFO     2016-01-24 10:48:30,904 module.py:787] default: "POST /process_file HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I think that 'DELETE' there is the culprit throwing my uploaded file away, but why ?

  Things I tried so far:
- If I omit the bucket then I will see an uploaded file in the blob store on the dev server, but since all the other files in the deployed application are in that bucket, I doubt this will work together nicely.

  If I store the file immediately in the blob store omitting the upload step, I get both a __BlobInfo__ and a __GsFileInfo__ entry in my datastore, but the filename field on the __BlobInfo__ is empty, and that just happened to be the key I was using to link the uploaded image back to the original record it came from, so the image could be served alongside it. (As you can see I experimented with a workaround for this already, but this info would then be missing on all the images already in the cloud right now, so still not a decent solution)

  ```
      file = cloudstorage.open("/my_bucket/%s" % filename,mode = "w", content_type = 'image/jpeg', options = {'x-goog-meta-original': filename})
      file.write(outputstream.getvalue())
      file.close()
  ```

  logging now looks like:

  ```
  INFO     2016-01-24 11:12:59,993 module.py:787] proc_mod: "POST /_ah/gcs/my_bucket/somefilename.jpg HTTP/1.1" 201 -
  INFO     2016-01-24 11:13:00,069 module.py:787] proc_mod: "PUT /_ah/gcs/my_bucket/somefilename.jpg?upload_id=encoded_gs_file%3AbWFyczNkL3NvbWV0aGluZy5qcGc%3D HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  ```

That second logging almost looks like what I always wanted, so my question is: Why does the upload get deleted and the cloudstorage writes get to stay ?
Is there a way to 'fix' whatever is going wrong ?
Update: Even though the file gets deleted, the called php page is still getting the information about it in it's $_FILES array:

```
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => somefilename.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => gs://my_bucket/fake-IrYBUvl5acdwBmDoOBKgCQ==
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 84916
        )
```

Comment: You mention that the file appears to be deleted. What are you using to determine the file(s) has/have been deleted? Could you also add this code to your example?

Comment: The logging says so:
`INFO     2016-01-24 10:48:30,891 module.py:787] proc_mod: "DELETE /_ah/gcs/my_bucket/fake-pywzB198-jubU_Kcl-REhA%3D%3D HTTP/1.1" 204 `
And also if I query my datastore there are no additional __BlobInfo__ entries there. But I found a solution which I will post in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it would now be mandatory to move the file after the upload. In PHP the function `move_uploaded_file` will do this. Not sure if it is due to asking the upload URL to Python that this happens, or if it is a new requirement that wasn't there when I first deployed my program almost 2 years ago. But just moving the file to a specific file name seems to do the trick to save the file contents before they get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct in that you must move the file or it will be automatically removed from Google Cloud Storage. As documented in the [Implementing file uploads](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload#implementing_file_uploads) article:

> Note: Any user uploaded files that are not moved using
>   `move_uploaded_file` or `rename` before the request finishes will be
>   automatically removed from Google Cloud Storage.

I have not quickly found any older documentation showing when this requirement may have changed.